# Why is ngModel not being loaded into my link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my directive, I'm setting ngModel as a dependency with `'require: '?ngModel'`. But whenever the link function is called, `ngModel` is undefined.

Here's my full code:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',

    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;
      console.log("This code never runs!");
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ng-model` attribute for this directive in your HTML file.

Example:

`<my-directive ng-model="foo"></my-directive>`